# Include content from another server in WordPress plugin page

Tags: php, curl, wordpress

I had something similar to what I hope to accomplish working a few months ago, and I'm not sure if an update within WordPress changed the necessary settings or what, but needless to say it doesn't work anymore. I need the following:

1. Blogger, with plugin installed, navigates to main plugin page and sees four or five draft posts.
2. Blogger finds post that they like, clicks it, and it creates a draft of the post for later review.
3. Everyone's happy.

The caveat is that those four or five posts change routinely, and the plugin page would have to have the most up-to-date posts. When I had this working, I was just doing a `file_get_contents` on the plugin page to get the content that we host. Then, I could make changes on our end that were reflected on theirs. They clicked a button, and it would `wp_insert_post()` a draft.

How could I accomplish this with cURL, or some PHP workaround that doesn't require changing the `allow_url_include` settings, or maybe some mimicked RSS feed...

Comment: How was your `file_get_contents` being done? What type of content was it retrieving?

Comment: @brasofilo it was retrieving the php source code from the file hosted on another server. Regardless, I got it figured out this afternoon, it just meant moving most of the logic to the plugin itself rather than have it hosted on a separate page.